# How activate built-in leds on a genius slimstar 8008 keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboards

Genius slimstar 8008 is a wireless keyboard + mouse.

Regarding keys, all seem to work as expected ( letters, Fn, ctrl, alt, a.s.o. )

There are built-in leds to indicate key state, num, lock, scroll, and for battery state.

It seems even with windows a driver is needed to activate them  → http://us.geniusnet.com/supports/slimstar-8008

So here is the naïve question : is there a way to enable them in ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 ?